# How can i add a package in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, package

[image]

I want to add a package to ui like actvt in ui.
How can i achieve it?

I can add it in folder.Can i add it in  Android Studio?

ui->
 - actvt
 - actvt2

[image]

Just disable the highlight I get what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project window of your IDE click on the options menu(small gear icon) and disable the "Flatten Packages" option. This will make things more straight forward.

From there you can simply right click on the ui package and select `new -> package` to create your `actvt2` package.

Comment: Thanks for provide ideas